# Flutter : Make Text Responsive In Different Size

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

I'm working with Responsive Screen and i have some problem about Responsive Text Widget.

To the point, I testing my app in 2 Emulator (1.Nexus S API 28 (Small), 2. Nexus 5(Big))
[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

In emulator **Nexus 5** Everything it's oke , but in **Nexus S** i have error `Bottom overflowed By 0.22222 Pixels`.

I know about `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and  `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`, i already used this for my Layout Card. But the problem i dont know how to manage Size Text widget in different Screen(I want Text size auto resize/scalling in different Screen).

Can you Help me ?

Thank's

#### It's My Code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData localTheme = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                // onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   PageTransition(
                //     type: PageTransitionType.upToDown,
                //     child: BeritaDetail(
                //       judulBerita: widget.judulBerita,
                //       isiBerita: widget.isiBerita,
                //       gambarBerita: widget.gambarBerita,
                //       tanggalKategori: widget.tanggalBerita,
                //       namaKategori: widget.namaKategori,
                //     ),
                //   ),
                // ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.judulBerita,
                          style: localTheme.textTheme.subhead,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                height: 30,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      widget.tanggalBerita,
                                      style: localTheme.textTheme.overline,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      widget.namaKategori,
                                      style: localTheme.textTheme.overline,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 30,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                    onPressed: () => "",
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                    onPressed: () => "",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl:
                    "${Urls.BASE_API_IMAGE}/berita/${widget.gambarBerita}",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The only thing I know is [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil), you could try and give us a feedback :)

Comment: @Tokenyet Thank's for your response, I already read the documentation , but i'm still confused to implement to my Text widget. Can you help me ? I'm already do this but idk it's right or not . `style:localTheme.textTheme.subhead.copyWith(fontSize:ScreenUtil(allowFontScaling: true).setSp(32)`
                          ),

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a text scale option for your app in builder context of the main file, something like:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      child: child,
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to wrap icons Container inside Expanded Widget.

```
                Expanded(
                      child:
                         Container(
                              height: 30,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                    onPressed: () => "",
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                    onPressed: () => "",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                           ),
```